Solve a very difficult integral with gamma functions
I have a very intricate integral because I am trying to integrate out the parameter $\tau$. Indeed, I have a multivariate variable $Z_i$ for $I = 1,\dots, N$, that is distributed as $Z_i \sim \prod_{k=1}^K \rm Bernoulli(\alpha_k)$ with $\alpha_k \sim Beta\left(\frac{b\tau_k}{K}, b\right)$ and $\tau_k \sim Gamma(r,s)$. I have already integrated out the parameter $\alpha$ and now I am trying to integrate out the parameter $\tau$ too for estimation purposes.
The starting integral is
$$\int_0^\infty \prod_{k=1}^K \frac{B\left(m_k + \frac{b\tau_k}{K}, N-m_k + b\right)}{B\left(\frac{b\tau_k}{K}, b\right)} \times \prod_{k=1}^K \frac{s^r}{\Gamma(r)} \tau_k^{r-1} e^{-s\tau_k} \,d\tau\\$$
where $m_k = \sum_N z_{ik}$.
After many many passages I ended up with the following result
$$ \prod_{k=1}^K \left\{s^r\Gamma(N-m_k + 1) \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{m_k - 1} l^{-N} p e^{-t -v -p -l}}{\left(s - \frac{1}{K}\left[\ln \left(\frac{t+v}{l+p}\right)\right]\right)^r} \,dt \,dl \,dp \,dv \right\}$$
and I don't know how to keep going from here on.
The quantities that depends on $Z_i$ and of which I am interested in are $m_K$ and $K$. Is there any way to solve it analytically?
To make it easier you can also (as I did) assume that the parameter of the Beta distribution $b$ is equal to 1.
Feel free to start from the beginning integral and come up with your own solution. I "just" need to integrate out $\tau_k$ for $k=1,\dots,K$.
Thank you in advance.

What did you try? Why do you think the integral has a nice closed form?

This is the result of a way bigger integral, in my research I would need to obtain a closed form but I am not managing because I don't know how to handle the denominator (the logarithm). This is why I am asking. Is there any way to handle it?

You should include your attempt, otherwise the question will be closed

It is like a two page latex attempt.. should I write it all?

While i am writing this comment, the question already has three [Close] votes. Please understand why from the perspective of the community. We have a question about an integral - but without knowing its importance, its origin. It comes in a too high generality with integer parameters that are hard to digest - there are also many $m_k$ values, they appear rather through $m_k-1$. There is a denominator to the power $r$, and $r$ is "an integer". It may be $0,-1,-2$ but also $1,2,3$. Even in these cases and for $k=1$ there is something to do - which does not look trivial. Which are the attempts?

Ok now I have contextualised the problem. If needed I can also provide the whole computation but, as I said, It is very long. Since I have no idea of how to keep going from here, there are no attempts. I have seen that when integrating for t in the numerator I get a gamma function of $m_k$ but I don't know how to deal with the denominator, so I have no attempt to show...
